# How do I login using a different user with customized listener and tns records in my services?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to connect to sqlplus using another user: HR. I am able to do so using sysdba but not using HR. It gives me TNS error.

I tried changing the passwords to be sure that no special characters cause any issue. But none of it worked.

This is how I login using sysdba:

```
sqlplus -L sys/metcs674@//localhost:7777/mtsports_db01 as sysdba
```

It works.

When I try to login using HR user:
`sqlplus -L hr/indicadls02//localhost:7777/mtsports_db01`, it fails.

The configuration files are:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

MTSPORTS_DB01 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = MTSPORTS_DB01)
    )
  )

ORCLCDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCLCDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

and:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 7777))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = MTSPORTS_NOCONN_9999))
    )
  )
```

I want to connect using the user `HR` but it gives me the following error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Oct 14 18:42:55 2019
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

    -H         Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
           usage help.
    -V         Displays the SQL*Plus version.

Usage 2: sqlplus [ [<option>] [{logon | /nolog}] [<start>] ]

  <option> is: [-AC] [-C <version>] [-F] [-L] [-M "<options>"] [-NOLOGINTIME]
           [-R <level>] [-S]

    -AC        Enable Application Continuity.
    -C <version>   Sets the compatibility of affected commands to the
           version specified by <version>.  The version has
           the form "x.y[.z]".  For example, -C 10.2.0
    -F         This option improves performance in general. It changes
           the default values settings.
           See SQL*Plus User's Guide for the detailed settings.
    -L         Attempts to log on just once, instead of
           reprompting on error.
    -M "<options>" Sets automatic HTML or CSV markup of output.  The options
           have the form:
           {HTML html_options|CSV csv_options}
           See SQL*Plus User's Guide for detailed HTML and CSV options.
    -NOLOGINTIME   Don't display Last Successful Login Time.
    -R <level>     Sets restricted mode to disable SQL*Plus commands
           that interact with the file system.  The level can
           be 1, 2 or 3.  The most restrictive is -R 3 which
           disables all user commands interacting with the
           file system.
    -S         Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
           the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
           commands.

  <logon> is: {<username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | / }
          [AS {SYSDBA | SYSOPER | SYSASM | SYSBACKUP | SYSDG
          | SYSKM | SYSRAC}] [EDITION=value]

    Specifies the database account username, password and connect
    identifier for the database connection.  Without a connect
    identifier, SQL*Plus connects to the default database.

    The AS SYSDBA, AS SYSOPER, AS SYSASM, AS SYSBACKUP, AS SYSDG,
    AS SYSKM and AS SYSRAC options are database administration privileges.

    <connect_identifier> can be in the form of Net Service Name
    or Easy Connect.

      @[<net_service_name> | [[//]Host[:Port]/<service_name>] |
    [[[protocol:]//]host1{,host12}[:port1]{,host2:port2}[/service_name]
     [:server][/instance_name][?[parameter_name=value]
     {&parameter_name=value}]]]

    <net_service_name> is a simple name for a service that resolves
    to a connect descriptor.

    Example: Connect to database using Net Service Name and the
         database net service name is ORCL.

       sqlplus myusername/mypassword@ORCL

    Host specifies the host name or IP address of the database
    server computer.

    Port specifies the listening port on the database server.

    <service_name> specifies the service name of the database you
    want to access.

    Example: Connect to database using Easy Connect and the
         Service name is ORCL.

       sqlplus myusername/mypassword@Host/ORCL

    The /NOLOG option starts SQL*Plus without connecting to a
    database.

    The EDITION specifies the value for Session Edition.


  <start> is: @<URL>|<filename>[.<ext>] [<parameter> ...]

    Runs the specified SQL*Plus script from a web server (URL) or the
    local file system (filename.ext) with specified parameters that
    will be assigned to substitution variables in the script.

When SQL*Plus starts, and after CONNECT commands, the site profile
(e.g. $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql) and the user profile
(e.g. login.sql in the working directory) are run.  The files may
contain SQL*Plus commands.

Refer to the SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference for more information.
```

Comment: Are you really missing the @ sign in the second connect string after the password?  It's a bit odd that your listener is set to the non-standard port 7777, you have a tnsnames.ora file but you're not using a TNS alias, and your TNS aliases reference the standard port of 1521.  That doesn't stop you from using the EZConnect syntax, it's just odd that you have those configuration differences

Comment: By adding the b`@`, I was able to login. Apologies to you and to the community for this blunder.

Do you think this question should be here? If yes and if you don't mind, can you answer this so that I can mark it as accepted?